# Best way to present alternative locations without implying a choice to customer

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, mobile-web

I work for a company which offers trips to customers.

Currently we present the hotels where a customer will stay in the following way:

[image]

This works well, and the response is great because it's easy to get an impression from the overall trip for the customers.

Right now we are converting more of an old website, and a lot of trips have alternative hotels at their stayover locations, which are similar, but where our travel agents usually decide based on wishes of clients which hotel to offer in their quote.

- Day 1-3: Client is in miami.
- choices: Daddy-o hotel and Trianon - same price, user experience
- currently displayed: trianon
- alternative, not displayed: daddy-o

But the wish exists to present those alternative hotels on our website, but our main focus is not:

- to convey the message that the customer has to choose at this point of the process(them viewing the website not having requested a quote yet)
- to make the customer insecure of what experience they'll get that stayover

Our focus is:

- Present alternative locations they might get
- Give them a bit of holiday feel already so they will be more inclined to request a obligation free quote.

So in essence, how could we present it to the customer in the best way, that's responsive web design friendly, without making them feel insecure about what the trip is about or that they "have to do something".

Basically we want the website presentation make the customer feel like they are going on this holiday, with as little distractions from that feel or complicated user interface elements.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but do you want to present an option to the user that s/he will never be able to choose? Or am I understanding it all wrong?

Comment: The customer will be able to actively choose once they have received a quote. For the first time customer we wish to give the *impression* of the trip so theyll request a quote, because customers always have wishes that differ from our standard packages

Answer (score 1):

You could try presenting the primary hotel and alternate as cards, with the primary accommodation presented as the top card. Show some details of the hotels on each card. Label the primary hotel card "Primary hotel" or "planned accommodations" or something like that, and make the primary hotel card background color brighter than the secondary one. Label the alternate something descriptive, like "Alternate Hotel". On click or tap, bring the alternate hotel to the top of the Z index so that the details are visible. In this way, it doesn't look like you have to make a choice, and you are transparent about there being a main hotel and a secondary. 
[image: Here's a visual example]

Comment: This seems like a nice intuitive way. Will experiment with this

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to mention the hotel which is **most popular** in bookings OR the **nearest hotel** to the user's selected or current location.

Below, you can have a drop-down or a button that mentions **View 1 More Location**.

[image]

As far as a holiday feel is concerned, I would advise you to switch to a better interface and use images to your advantage. The current one feels more of a luxurious website but nothing that ignites excitement into the user. I would also advise to increase the font size and have images fill the width and use text over the image with a black overlay over the image.

Comment: We alrready have parts where background images are used. This is situated in a white part between background images parts. This was choosen because hotel lists can be very long for 3 week trips and are actually hidden with a show more if more than 2 hotels.

Comment: So, you are giving the option to see the other hotels only if there are two hotels?

Comment: Yes. Basically there will usually be one hotel, but there are cases there are two hotels that can be presented. Only when one alternative is defined itll be shown.

Comment: What do you think about the button approach in the image I have presented in my answer?

Comment: I like it. But im a coder :-p i need to try to see it from the customers perspective too. Will the button not give confusion? The urge to act and not being really sure what it means? First lesson i learned in designing websites is that user are incredibly simple minded and if its not clear what something does it either makes them insecure or ignore it

Comment: It's straightforward as it is. I would recommend testing it on a group of users and observe how they react to the new addition and what do they do.

Comment: Well, the pages it runs on is already part of an ab-test. I can easely implement it as part of the test. But then i also need an alternative to test against

Comment: Show both hotels as the alternative.